# How do i implement followers and following with homefeed in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, social-networking

I'm making a Twitter like ios app (just for practicing my programming). I just wondered, because i couldn't find that much online about this stuff, what is the best way (or the most ideal way), to implement following/followers system in Firebase? Like say Mark follows Derek, then Derek makes a tweet, then Mark gets Derek's tweet in his home feed.

Would be great if someone could share their thoughts on this.

Comment: In my Opinion, this is a usecase for an HTML5 Progressive WebApp. In Html5 you can use the Websocket functionality of firebase to broadcast changed to any connected Device.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is: If user A activates the follow-function on user B, the uid of user B gets in the following-node of user A, and user A gets in the followers-node of user B.

After that, there are multiple ways to implement the feed. One way is to go to the tweets of user B and push them to the feed of user A. If user B posts a tweet, loop through his followers and push the key of that tweet to the feeds of his followers. So user A now has the old tweet keys and potential new tweet keys on his feed-node. You can now loop through these keys and get the data from an alltweets-node.

Another way is to let user A loop through his following-node and get the tweets of all the people he follows from their tweet-nodes. You can than join these tweets and sort them by date. A tweet now only has to be posted in the alltweets-node and in the tweets-node of one user, instead of pushing the tweet key to the feed-node of every follower he has.

Just two ways to achieve this, there are certainly more ways to do this, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please clearify what you mean "loop through his following node" and how i can achive this in xCode with firebase? I already have made the nodes in the database with "following / uid /  uid of the people he is following ", and the same goes for followers. But how can i get the uids of the people currentUser is following, and furthermore go inside the .child (tweets). child (uid) node of all the people currentUser is following?